# What does this mathematical notation mean?

Tags: notation

Please excuse this simple question, but I cannot seem to find an answer. I'm not very experienced with math, but I keep seeing a notation that I would like explained. The notation I am referring too generally is one variable m floating over another variable n enclosed in paraentheses. You can see an example in the first equation [here](http://jeremykun.wordpress.com/2012/12/02/ramsey-number-lower-bound/).

What does this mean? Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That notation is read "$n$ choose $m$", and it indicates the number of ways one can choose $m$ objects from a collection of $n$ objects, if we don't care about "order".  Think about a bag of 10 things...how many different ways can I pick 5 objects out of the bag?  That number is $\binom{10}{5}$.

Answer (score 8):

This is called the ***binomial coefficent***, often read "n choose m", since it provides a way of computing the number of ways to choose $m$ items from a collection of $n$ items, provided the order or arrangement of those items doesn't matter.

To compute the binomial coefficient: $\displaystyle \binom{n}{m}$, you can use the factorial formula: $$\binom{n}{m} = \binom{n}{n-m}=\frac{n!}{m!(n-m)!}$$

Answer (score 7):

That is a [binomial coefficient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient). $\binom{n}{m}$ means the number of subsets of size $m$ of a fixed set of size $n$.